# Abstract typing and multiple dispatch for functions in julia

Tags: julia, abstract-data-type, multiple-dispatch

I want to have objects interact with specific interactions depending on their type.

Example problem: I have four particles, two are type A, and 2 are type B. when type A's interact I want to use the function

```
function interaction(parm1, parm2)
    return parm1 + parm2
end
```

when type B's interact I want to use the function

```
function interaction(parm1, parm2)
        return parm1 * parm2
    end
```

when type A interacts with type B I want to use function

```
function interaction(parm1, parm2)
        return parm1 - parm2
    end
```

These functions are purposefully over simple.

I want to calculate a simple summation that depends on pairwise interactions:

```
struct part
    parm::Float64
end

# part I need help with:
# initialize a list of length 4, where the entries are `struct part`, and the abstract types
# are `typeA` for the first two and `typeB` for the second two. The values for the parm can be
# -1.0,3, 4, 1.5 respectively

energy = 0.0
for i in range(length(particles)-1)
    for j = i+1:length(particles)
        energy += interaction(particles[i].parm, particles[j].parm)
    end
end

println(energy)
```

assuming the use of parameters being `particle[1].parm = -1`, `particle[2].parm = 3`, `particle[3].parm = 4`, `particle[4].parm = 1.5`, energy should account for the interactions of

```
(1,2) = -1 + 3 = 2
(1,3) = -1 - 4 = -5
(1,4) = -1 - 1.5 = -2.5
(2,3) = 3 - 4 = -1
(2,4) = 3 - 1.5 = 1.5
(3,4) = 4 * 1.5 = 6

energy = 1
```

Doing this with `if statements` is almost trivial but not extensible. I am after a clean, tidy Julia approach...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this (I use the simplest form of the implementation as in this case it is enough and it is explicit what happens I hope):

```
struct A
    parm::Float64
end

struct B
    parm::Float64
end

interaction(p1::A, p2::A) = p1.parm + p2.parm
interaction(p1::B, p2::B) = p1.parm * p2.parm
interaction(p1::A, p2::B) = p1.parm - p2.parm
interaction(p1::B, p2::A) = p1.parm - p2.parm # I added this rule, but you can leave it out and get MethodError if such case happens

function total_energy(particles)
    energy = 0.0
    for i in 1:length(particles)-1
        for j = i+1:length(particles)
            energy += interaction(particles[i], particles[j])
        end
    end
    return energy
end

particles = Union{A, B}[A(-1), A(3), B(4), B(1.5)] # Union makes sure things are compiled to be fast

total_energy(particles)
```

Answer (score -3):

I have no idea how to do this in your language, but what you need is an analogue to what we call the strategy pattern in object-oriented programming. A strategy is a pluggable, reusable algorithm. In Java I’d make an interface like:

```
interface Interaction<A, B>
{
    double interact(A a, B b)
}
```

Then implement this three times and reuse those parts wherever you need things to interact. Another method can take an Interaction and use it without knowing how it’s implemented. I think this is the effect you’re after. Sorry I don’t know how to translate into your dialect.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally bad some multiple dispatch is a feature of Julia which obsoletes almost so if the gang of 4 "design pattern" abominations.

Comment: Uh, multiple dispatch is not some kind of cure-all for a host of reasons.

Comment: Maybe not all, but for surprisingly many: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kc9HwsxE1OY. And the rest, I guess, is covered by higher-order functions :)

Comment: Well sure. You can implement everything in a Turing machine. In my mind the question is "what is the appropriate tool for the job?"

Comment: Multiple dispatch is definitely a cure for this particular pattern. But it is of course interesting to demonstrate how awkward this is to implement in languages *without* multiple dispatch.